# Can I make a polymorphic `mult` function, that takes any numeric type?

Tags: haskell, types, numbers, polymorphism

I'm learning Haskell. This is the very first program that I've ever wrote and I just thought of making a simple function that returns the product of the given arguments.

```
mult :: a -> a -> a
mult x y = x * y
```

When I write it this way, I get an "inferred type" error.

```
ERROR "uno.hs":5 - Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : mult
*** Expected type : a -> a -> a
*** Inferred type : Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

It wants me to write it this way:

```
mult :: Int -> Int -> Int
mult x y = x * y
```

...which works perfectly fine, but then I wonder... can't this function work on `Float`s as well?

It can.

```
mult :: Float -> Float -> Float
mult x y = x * y

--then
mult 4 5 == 20.0
```

Finally, I wonder:

**Can I make a polymorphic `mult` function, that takes any numeric type?**

**Why does the parser infers `Integrer` from a function that also works with other types?**

I found no answers so far, yet this seems like a simple question. I'll be grateful for help me.

Comment: You signature suggests that we can multiply two elements of *any* type. I think we agree how to multiply `Int`s and `Float`s, but what about `Bool`, `String`, and my custom `Foo` type? It seems like you might need to constrain the types that are allowed in your `mult` function with a *constraint*.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, nor can I find information about constraints that is easy to understand!

Comment: Ok, so I've tried `mult :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a` but I have an "ambiguous class occurrence" error now.

Comment: NOTE: The code in the last comment works perfectly fine. The error was because I was using an outdated parser (Hugs). It works fine using GHC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: `mult :: Num a => a -> a -> a` and it picked `Integer` because it felt like it was a good choice.

Long answer:

`mult` can't be `a -> a -> a` because that would mean it works on *every* type `a`, including String, Char, Bool, etc. The `Num a =>` part is called a *constraint*, and it restricts what `a` can be by requiring that it is an *instance* of the `Num` *type class*. It's like saying "this function works on any type, as long as that type has the properties (has an instance) of this specific type class". The properties for the `Num` type class are defined in the standard library, linked below.

It's worth noting that the type of `(*)` itself is `Num a => a -> a -> a`, and that your function `mult` could also have been defined as `mult = (*)`.

The reason it told you to use `Integer -> Integer -> Integer` is because the default for `Num` is Integer. You should never rely on this being the case, and should instead write out the full, type class constrained type signature.

When you specified the type signature `Float -> Float -> Float`, the compiler specializes the function to only work on `Float`s, as you would expect. This resolves the "over-promising" problem arising from `a -> a -> a` by choosing a specific type for `a` that the compiler knows has a `Num` instance.

Read more about type classes [here](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html), and the specific definition of `Num` is documented [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) and the code is linked on the side of the page. (Not enough rep to post the link directly)

Comment: Ok so this seems to solve the answer but I can't make it work. Apparently the problem is with the interpreter "Hugs" I'm using. I'll accept the answer because I understood now what a constraint is and how to solve the problem :)

Comment: IIRC, Hugs is a very outdated Haskell compiler/interpreter that was discontinued. I recommend that you use GHC instead (or better yet, get the [Haskell Stack Tool](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) to use GHC for you)

Comment: Indeed I installed GHC and now my code works!! :D Thanks for the help